# ImageResizer: force update of diskcache to new folder

Tags: image-resizing, imageresizer-diskcache

Hi: I migrated a website from one server to another, and in the process copied the diskcache folder, but some of the cache images did not copy. (I have a diskcache license.) The other server is no longer accessible.

The original images are all there, but I'm getting a missing image icon for missing cached images. I'm happy to just delete the entire cache and let imageresizer rebuild it, but i'm not sure what the proper way to do this is?

I  tried creating a second cache folder, and updated the plugin section with the path to the new folder, but it doesn't seem to be working (the new folder is not being populated):

```
    <resizer>
    <pipeline fakeExtensions=".ashx" />

<plugins>
<add name="DiskCache" dir="~/imagecache2" />
</plugins></resizer>
```

I also updated imageresizer and the diskcache plugin from 3.3.3 to 4.0.5 (using nuget), and restarted the web application and website. Am I doing something wrong, or leaving something out?

[EDIT]--I re-read the instructions and corrected my web.config:

```
    <resizer>
    <pipeline fakeExtensions=".ashx" />
    <plugins>
        <add name="DiskCache"/>
      </plugins>
    <diskCache dir="~/imagecache2" subfolders="256" autoClean="true" asyncWrites="true" />
</resizer>
```

But I'm still not seeing anything being written to the new folder...do I need to explicitly give write permissions on this folder on the server?

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone else, the issue was assigning change privileges on the folder to the app user account!